# Integral - $\int_{0}^{1} \log^4(1-x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Integral - $$\int_{0}^{1} \log^4(1-x) dx$$

**Please do not give a full answer.**

The issue is the fourth power of the log.  I could use that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_nx^n = \frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x}$$

But integration only gets that to the second power.

Ideas?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=1-x$, and then see [History of the $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the transformation $1-e^{-z}=x$, In general the answer will be $$\int_{0}^1\ln^n(1-x)dx=(-1)^n n!,\ n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: (+1) though, That is wrong. Its 24.

Comment: This is a full answer, the OP wanted a hint.

Comment: @GFauxPas, the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Lebes That doesn't make it better.

Comment: @GFauxPas, I started writing the answer misreading "Please give a full answer", my bad, guess I am sleepy now. I am editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: IBP 4 times, as you would have done with a $p=1$: $\int_{0}^{1} 1 \cdot \log^4x dx = x \log x \bigg|_0^1 - 4 \int_{0}^{1}\log^3 x dx$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the integral

$$ I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^\alpha\, dx = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}. $$

So the original integral can be evaluated using $I(\alpha)$ as

$$\int_{0}^{1} \log^4(1-x) dx= \frac{d^4}{d \alpha^4} I(\alpha)\bigg|_{\alpha =0} = 24. $$

Comment: I am tempted to downvote because you gave a full answer to his question when he specificly asked you not to.